# Не понимаю, как передать массив структур в функцию си

Tags: c

Мне нужно передать массив структур в функцию, но я допускаю где-то ошибку:

> address_analysis.c:20:25: предупреждение: «struct str_analysis» декларированное внутри списка параметров не будет видно вне этого определения или декларации char addr_people(struct str_analysis art){
>
> address_analysis.c:20:38: ошибка: параметр 1 («art») имеет неполный тип
>    char addr_people(struct str_analysis art){

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAS 100 
#define ADDR 10


typedef struct{
    char city[MAS];
    char street[MAS];
    char house[MAS];
}address;

typedef struct{
    char name[MAS];
    address *addr;
    int bs;
}people[ADDR];

char addr_people(struct str_analysis art){  
    printf("%d", art[1].bs);
}

int main(){
    /*Заполняем структуру*/
    people str_analysis;
    str_analysis[1].bs = 10;
    addr_people(&str_analysis);
    return 0;
}
```

Из того, что я нашол я не понял, что вызывает у меня ошибку.

Comment: Что такое `struct str_analysis` и зачем вы это туда вписали?

Comment: Как я  понимаю, struct str_analysis - это указатель на структуру.

Comment: В языке С `struct str_analysis` - это **имя типа**. Компилятор в первый раз видит этот тип и не знает что это за тип такой. Именно поэтому он и говорит вам: что это за неизвестный тип и к чему он здесь вдруг появился?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите `struct` из объявления функции и передавайте не массив, а указатель на него, а-ля

`void addr_people(people *art)`

Собственно вызов будет

```
addr_people(&str_analysis);
```

Comment: Нет. Так будет неправильно. Если вы хотите вызов `addr_people(str_analysis)`, то функция должна быть объявлена с параметром `people art`, а не `people *art`. `people art` и так будет указателем.

Comment: Можно сделать и `void addr_people(people *art)`, но тогда правильный вызов будет `addr_people(&str_analysis)`. Либо так, либо эдак, но не так, как у вас.

Comment: Во втором варианте аргументом является **указатель на массив**. При вызове `str_analysis` - это сам массив. Чтобы получить **указатель на массив**, при вызове нужно сделать `&str_analysis`. Компилятор вам сам об этом скажет, если вы попробуете. Что у вас там за свой пример, я не знаю - мне отсюда не видно.

Comment: Протупил... точно